# Conditional Rendering the components, Next.js style broken on first load

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, antd

I am using Ant Design and Custom Stylesheet. On first load style is broken, but when I visit another page and come back to broken page, now it looks fine. So the problem is only on the first load. It's on the development server, I have been clear all cache. But still the same issue.

Here is the screenshot how it's looking like after first load

[image]

Here is the correct style after I come back from another page

[image]

Here is the code how I am rendering the components:

```
<div>
  {jwToken || role === "restaurant_owner" ? (
    <Layout>
      <Index />
    </Layout>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <Login />
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a simliar issue, the way I fixed it was to add a `mounted` variable that depended on the condition. So it looks this.

```js
// Not sure how you pass the condition, I'm assuming hooks
const { condition } = someHook()

const [mounted, setMounted] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
   setMounted(true)
   return () => setMounted(false)
}, [condition]);

return (
   <div>
       {mounted && condition && <Component/>
   </div>
)
```

As to why this happens, I suspect it has to do with SSR (I found simliar [issue on Github but for Material-UI](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8400)) and my solution forces the condition to be available only during the browser.